# Dwr issues on latest browser version like firefox 16+

Tags: dwr

i wrote the java application making use of DWR to filter and populate some filds eg continent to countries, the application works fine with Firefox 14 but when i do upgrade my Firefox version it does not work also on google chrome it doesnt work.
any help please...

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, I have not problems wiht FF 16 or 17.
What DWR version do you have?

You can paste some code of your app.